# Record gets inserted successfully but doesn't show up in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert a record in table containing 105 columns. The record gets inserted successfully but when I try to select the same record it doesn't show up.
I'm in the same session and also I tried to apply commit and select it again but could see no luck. Could anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you `commit` the inserts? Show us the SELECT query that doesn't return anything. Any triggers involved?

Comment: Put the sql so we can at least debug

Comment: Yes, as i said, i have already applied commit.Triggers are involved but they are not taking any insert/update/delete action on the same table.

Comment: Commit is irrelevant if same session, disable trigger and see if fixes. If so then the trigger is the culprit. Maybe the trigger fails and rolls back

Comment: Sorry i cannot post as that would be against the organisation policy. If at all query had any error it would show some constraint violation or any other error but it shows 1 row inserted. So I guess there won't be any error in query. Could anyone please suggest what else needs to be checked?

Comment: Disable trigger and try it, maybe the 1row is inserted but a post insert trigger fails, and the error is suppressed and it rolls back

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. Bit afraid as its prod.

Comment: Umm. Do it in a test environment for gods sake

Comment: Thanks @AbBennett - Its the trigger that was creating an issue. The trigger was increasing the sequence of the primary key column and at the same time i was trying to pass my manual value in primary key column. So when i searched the inserted record with the primary key value i provided, i couldn't get any. Latter i saw i had inserted 10 rows with different primary key values(which was actually a sequence, automatically incremented by a trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @AbBennett - Its the trigger that was creating an issue. The trigger was increasing the sequence of the primary key column and at the same time i was trying to pass my manual value in primary key column. So when i searched the inserted record with the primary key value which I provided while insertion, i couldn't find any record. Latter I saw I had inserted 10 rows with different primary key values(which was actually a sequence, automatically incremented by a trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Create trigger like this and see what happens when you inserts:

```
create or replace trigger xyz_log after insert or update or delete on xyz for each row
begin
  if Inserting then
    dbms_output.put_line('Row inserted: ' || :new.rowid);
  elsif Updating then
    dbms_output.put_line('Row updated: ' || :new.rowid);
  elsif Deleting then
    dbms_output.put_line('Row deleted: ' || :old.rowid);
  end if;
end;
```